# The best way to create connection to OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I create a connection to the database is as follows:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:host1/test")
    .open("admin", "admin");
```

I have 2 nodes of DB.
When I shutdown node, which was in constructor, then throws exception:

```
Database 'plocal:/root/orientdb/databases/test' is closed
```

Of course, I can catch this exception and create new connection to another server, but I think, this is wrong.

Is there way to create connection to full DB, not to single node of cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you run 2 servers in cluster the switch is supposed to be automatic and transparent. But start 2 nodes using dserver.sh/bat instead of server.sh/bat and assure two nodes see each other. Look at this tutorial: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Tutorial%3A-setup-a-distributed-database

Comment: I run servers using dserver.sh. And I see, that node is in cluster, because when I insert record from first host by Studio, I can see in second host Studio that this record exist.

Comment: So the node should automatically switch. Can you try with the console? connect to a node, kill it and type a command like "info" to see if it switch to the other node.